# Cannot view PHP page in browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've set up my ec2 instance, uploaded a test php file to var/www/html and updated the `httpd.conf` file successfully as mentioned in blogs/documentation.

Now I want to view my php file in my browser. I am trying to open my `Public DNS` in web browser but the browser cannot open it. Google chrome says:

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to ec2-54-218-xxx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: Have you set up public access on port 80 (or whatever port you are using) in your security profile?

Comment: yes, in both inbound and outbound I've added 0.0.0.0/0 for 80(HTTP). 
But it's still not working.

Comment: Did you restart Apache?

Comment: I restarted the EC2 instance. Would that restart Apache?

Comment: Not necessarily, if Apache is not set to start on boot.

Comment: Can you please let me know how can I reset Apache?

Comment: Ooh I got it. After updating the httpd.conf file I forgot to run this command: `sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart`

Comment: @MikeBrant | does resetting httpd means resetting Apache? Really sorry for silly questions, this is my first day on AWS.

Comment: Restarting Apache is not something specific to AWS.  Just run whatever command (like the one you have shown) that works for your linux distro.

Comment: @MikeBrant | yes, the above command worked. Thanks :-)

Comment: how did you, Adil Malik, "updated the httpd.conf file"???

Comment: @coolcool1994 Please check this out: http://www.alexkorn.com/blog/2011/03/getting-php-mysql-running-amazon-ec2/

Comment: @coolcool1994 Specially ready the "Web Server" part.

Comment: Thank you! I added my answer so that others could benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get into the server through terminal, I modified this file httpd.conf by terminal command "`sudo vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`" by uncommenting VirtualHost in the last few lines of the document (it is a really long document).

Under VirtualHost I also uncommented the DocumentRoot and changed its field to /var/www/html/ Now I can access this php file from the web browser by this url "myPublicDNSFromElasticIP"+/myPHPfileName. (YOU have to transfer your php file to /var/www/html/HERE in order to display it in the web or gain access from your mobile applications. You can do this by scp command in terminal)

You need to make a new PublicDNS by going into Elastic IP in the amazon Web EC2 console. so this myPublicDNSFromElasticIP is that new Public DNS from Elastic IP.

Also after you modify the file httpd.conf, you need to restart httpd I used this command in the terminal.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

And of course you need to download php from terminal using command sudo yum install php in order to get php to work

I used two websites. First website was a bit more helpful but the second from Adil was also helpful

http://www.alexkorn.com/blog/2011/03/getting-php-mysql-running-amazon-ec2/
http://www.rndmr.com/amazon-aws-ec2-easy-web-serverset-up-guide-with-a-mac-and-coda-2-256/

Comment: In value of `DocumentRoot`, you don't need to mention the file name. You can just write `/var/www/html`. This will allow access to the whole directory.

Comment: Also, please mention the URL of the article in your answer. So, people can read the full article if they want. Please update your answer and then I'll accept it.

Comment: Yes I corrected the DocumentRoot mistake. I updated my answer. Also I used an additional link to find the answer.